# Format "Content" in ToC when using memoir + titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, titlesec

In the following MWE the title of the ToC does not use the formatting from titlesec, as the other chapters do.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {}% format applied to label+text
  {\vspace{-60pt}\upshape\fontsize{72pt}{96pt}\selectfont\thechapter}% label
  {-10pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\vspace{5pt}\titlerule]% after the title body

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  [display]
  {}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {-10pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\vspace{5pt}\titlerule]% after the title body

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Numbered Test}
\chapter*{Unnumbered Test}
\end{document}
```

This seems to be a problem from combining memoir and titlesec. Can anyone tell me, what memoir does different to, e.g., book, where the above code works as intended?

Comment: Hasn't `memoir` own commands to modify headings and ToC entries? You should use these commands instead of `titlesec`. See chapter 6 and 9 in the `memoir` user manual.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Like KOMA and `titlesec` shouldn't be used together `memoir` and `titlesec` are no friends ;-)

Comment: I changed the chapterformatting to use the commands of the `memoir` class. Should I add this as an answer, or delete the question?

Comment: It's fine to add it as an answer. You're not the first person to try to use `titlesec` with `memoir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, not using `titlesec` together with `memoir` solves this issue. The code for above chapter styles in terms of `memoir`'s macros is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%%% Chapter Style %%%
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\fontsize{72pt}{96pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{darkgray}}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnumfont}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vspace*{-10pt}\hrulefill\vskip\afterchapskip}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{\baselineskip}

%%% ToC Style %%%
\newlength{\aftertocskip}
\setlength{\aftertocskip}{-15pt}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\par\nobreak\vspace*{-10pt}\hrulefill\vskip\aftertocskip}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Numbered Test}
\chapter*{Unnumbered Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you put this into a minimal document, like you did in your question?

Comment: yup, just updated my answer